# detect if your website run in background

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to detect if my website runing in background ,
for example : my website is open in browser but the user standing on the other tab 
youtube for example.

Comment: You want to know if your website's scripts are still running ? Well, I'd tend to say that yes it is. Depending on the browser, but by now multi-tasking is really popular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ifvisible.js](https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js/), [demo](http://serkanyersen.github.io/ifvisible.js/demo.html)

> Crossbrowser & lightweight way to check if user is looking at the page
>   or interacting with it.

Use [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API), [demo](http://daniemon.com/tech/webapps/page-visibility/)

> The Page Visibility API lets you know when a webpage is visible or in
>   focus. With tabbed browsing, there is a reasonable chance that any
>   given webpage is in the background and thus not visible to the user.
>   When the user minimizes the webpage or moves to another tab, the API
>   sends a visibilitychange event regarding the visibility of the page.
>   You can detect the event and perform some actions or behave
>   differently. For example, if your web app is playing a video, it would
>   pause the moment the user looks at another browser, and plays again
>   when the user returns to the tab. The user does not lose their place
>   in the video and can continue watching.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `window.onfocus` and `window.onblur` should work for your scenario.

Comment: Blur event even fires if we have clicked on Address Bar of browser, is there any way we can track this case?

Answer (score 3):

use [jQuery blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) for this:

```
$(window).blur(function(){ console.log("blur"); })
```

tested in my console on stackoverflow and it throws the console message when I go to a different tab.

Answer (score 1):

Check This below link. I hope you get your answare

1.[Possible to detect if a user has multiple tabs of your site open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038629/possible-to-detect-if-a-user-has-multiple-tabs-of-your-site-open)

2.[Check if my website is open in another tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690666/check-if-my-website-is-open-in-another-tab)