# How to know if user is logged in to my SAAS from different tab

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, session, cookies

I have a SAAS software with Laravel 5.2 (PHP).

Tab A - Is my SAAS website.

Tab B - Is my client website.

SAME BROWSER

My client log-in to my system on Tab A.

I want to present something on Tab B(Client website) but only if I know that he is logged-in in Tab A or have session/cookie because of the logged-in on Tab A

How can I do it / Detect it?

Comment: You want tab-b to just pick up the user login from tab-a? Or you want tab-b to work it out next time it submits to the site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to detect if a user has multiple tabs of your site open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038629/possible-to-detect-if-a-user-has-multiple-tabs-of-your-site-open)

Comment: @JeremyHarris Thank you, But it's didn't help :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
I want to present something on Tab B but (Client website) but only if I know that he is logged-in in Tab A or have session/cookie because of he logged-in in Tab A

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach is to allow the server to send websocket messages notifying all other browser tabs about the sign in event, which can then trigger a page reload for instance.